# Switching between activities Android studio Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So I'm building this application, and I have to implement a navigation drawer. Everything works fine except the switching between the activities part. I've been trying to solve this problem for days, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

drawermenu.xml (which is in the menu directory)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/change_event" android:title="changeevent" android:onClick="onClick"/>
<item android:id="@+id/home" android:title="home" android:onClick="onClick"/>
<item android:id="@+id/schedule" android:title="schedule" android:onClick="onClick"/>
<item android:id="@+id/workshops" android:title="workshops" android:onClick="onClick"/>
<item android:id="@+id/map" android:title="map" android:onClick="onClick"/>
<item android:id="@+id/faq" android:title="faq" android:onClick="onClick"/>


</menu>
```

This is the click event in my MainActivity.Java file (which is in the Java directory)

```
 public void onClick(MenuItem item) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Home.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

UPDATE

I added an onOptionsItemSelected event in the MainActivity.xml

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.change_event:
            // go to activity2
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SceduleActivity.class);
            // dispose the current activity while launching the next intent
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This still is not working I'm completely lost right now. I hope someone has an answer for me :)

Comment: What happens when you click on a menu item? Does your app crash? If so please show the stack trace.

Comment: No, it does not crash when I click a menu item.